Logrotate runs specific config only when executed manually
The legacy software (tango-controls) I am currently using on our servers stores logs in /var/tmp/ds.log as opposed to /var/log usually used by other software and I can't just change it. This software (or at least this version) doesn't have any log rotation routines so I have to use logrotate to prevent it from eating whole disk space.
I have following config in /etc/logrotate.d/tango:
/var/tmp/ds.log/*.log {
    missingok
    daily
    create 0644 tango tango
    compress
    notifempty
    rotate 30
    prerotate
        /root/tango_logrotate_prerotate_script.sh || true
    endscript
}

This prerotate script creates "old" directory in /var/tmp/ds.log if it does not exist, moves some very specific log files there and gzip-compresses them. After that all the remaining log files should be processed by logrotate automatically.
What happens?
In /var/lib/logrotate/logrotate.status I see these files were checked/seen by logrotate but no files were rotated and this custom script was not executed at all.
What should happen?
Manually executing logrotate -vf /etc/logrotate.d/tango does exactly what I wanted.
What am I missing?

Logrotate is started by daily cron, not from systemd, so I don't think systemd tweaks can be applied here.
